# How to run Python 3 in Sublime 2 REPL Mac

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext, read-eval-print-loop, sublimerepl

My question is the following, I have sublime 2 and sublime repl plugin installed all working fine, the only thing i need is to change the version of python that is running on the sublimerepl built in console. What I mean is, I have python 2.7.5 (which is pre installed with maveriks) running fine in sublime (via sublimerepl), and I have installed via the installer from python.org, python 3.3.3 , that I need to use, I want to run this version of python on the sublimerepl console but I don't know how.

I know that there are alternatives to sublime but none of those are so beautiful as sublime is.

Can someone help me with this ? I've searched for all over the internet and couldn't find anything helpful.

Btw if I use terminal python 3.3.3 is working fine (Terminal>'python3'), I know this is possible beacause a friend of mine got it working and I have installed mine like he did, but mine is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@poke's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20777468/1426065) is good, but there are a few details to correct that I figured I'd just put in my own answer as they're too long for comments. First, the `.sublime-menu` entry should be named `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu` (naming the file something else won't integrate it into the menu system, it has to be `Main.sublime-menu` AFAIK). Also, for your system, you should probably change the `"cmd"` lines to point to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3`, which is where the python.org installation is located. So, for example, where it says

```
"cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"],
```

change that to

```
"cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3", "-i", "-u"],
```

Good luck!

Comment: You’re right about the `Main.sublime-menu`, thanks! However if OP can run Python 3 using `python3` from the terminal, then it’s likely in the path, so you shouldn’t need to specify the full path.

Comment: @poke - one of the issues on OS X is that the `$PATH` seen by programs launched from the Dock is `/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin` by default (Mavericks may have added `/usr/local/bin`), and they don't see the shell's `$PATH` settings. Therefore, I figured it'd be better to specify the exact path. Of course, one could always make a symlink to `/usr/bin/python3`...

Comment: I only find it at ./Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu but there is no reference of Python. (2.0.2 build 2221)

Comment: @huggie - It's `Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`.

Comment: Got ya thanks. It's a separate package that doesn't come with sublime by default.

Answer (score 1):

Like it or not, but the interpreter is actually *hardcoded* into the plugin. For Python, this happens in [`/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu).

I think you have two ways to work around this:

1. The first option would be to copy that `Main.sublime-menu` file into your local user configuration folder, if you already have one there, you will need to merge both contents. Replace all the `python` calls by `python3`, and adjust the `caption` properties to mention `Python 3` (e.g. `Python 3 - RUN current file`).

   Now, when you launch the command launcher via Cmd+Shift+P (should be the keyboard shortcut in OSX, right?), then you can type `Python 3` and your new commands using the `python3` executable should pop up.
2. The second option would be to clone the plugin into your plugin directory, and modify the original Python `Main.sublime-menu` file in the same way as in the first option. This will get rid of the Python 2 commands, but also prevent you from getting updates from the original repository published over PackageManager; so you would have to make updates yourself.

Comment: Thank both of you so much ! poke and MattDMoo now it is finally runnning python 3.3.3.

Comment: @jbernardo You’re welcome. Note that, apart from accepting an answer, you can still *upvote* multiple answers if they helped you solve your problem to express your gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

my workaround was this:

Open the file:
/Users/ricardomartinez/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu

replace the line that says:

```
"cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "-m", "pdb", "$file_basename"],
```

with:

```
"cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3", "-i", "-u"],
```

note that is necessary specify the whole route of the python3 exec because i read in another question that Sublime don't read the ~/.bash_profile

Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the directory to

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3

This way whenever you update python, SublimeREPL will always get the updated version.